# Importing matplotlib returns "ModuleNotFoundError" after installing matplotlib with pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, python-import

I'm trying to display data using a pie chart in python, so i tried to install matplotlib using pip. After doing that, I tried importing matplotlib but I get an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'.

In the Command Prompt I typed 'pip install matplotlib' and everything appeared to be successful. This is the last line:

```
Successfully installed backports.functools-lru-cache-1.5 cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.0.1 matplotlib-2.2.4 numpy-1.16.2 pyparsing-2.3.1 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2018.9 six-1.12.0
```

I've also tried 'python -m pip install -U matplotlib', but I still get a ModuleNotFoundError.

I've tried running the input statement in both python 3 and 2, neither worked.

I've looked at various different discussions on this, and none of them seemed to help me. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it just matplotlib that won't import, or any library that you have installed through pip?

Answer (score 0):

There are various python installed in your OS. If you install matplotlib for somewhere the python that you are using does not search, you get importing errors. You should figure out which python you want to use and where the packages it searches.

Answer (score -1):

check your python path. the matplotlib should be installed in the same path with your python environment.

I guess you use an IDE to run the python. some IDE have their own python environment.

if not solved. plz introduce some details about your system、how installed etc.